# What does a geostationary satellite move relative to?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, orbital-motion, entropy, satellites

What does a geostationary satellite move relative to? I can't come up with a good answer. You don't move relative to the center, neither do you move relative to any location on the Earth. Does entropy stay constant?

Comment: Since the Earth rotates...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geostationary_orbit

Comment: I was writing an answer for Worldbuilding.SE a few days ago and chose 'geosynchronous' over 'geostationary' for exactly this reason. Lagrangian points could be considered geostationary, but Earth-orbiting satellites are at best geosynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

1. The Sun.
2. The Moon.
3. [An Earth-centered, non-rotating inertial reference frame.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth-centered_inertial)
4. The surface of the Earth*.

(*) If the Earth were a perfect, uniform sphere then item #4 wouldn't make the list. But Earth isn't a perfect sphere, and it isn't uniform in density. Specifically, it has a bit of longitudinal (east-west) lumpiness. That lumpiness will cause even a precisely placed satellite in Geosynchronous orbit to drift towards either $105^\circ$W or $75^\circ$E. 
[image]
The dashed line is the Geosynchronous orbit. The radial direction is scaled heavily from between 5 and 6 Earth radii.
[image]
(my apologies for the crappy scale on the y-axis, but the qualitative aspects are there).
The rate of drift depends on your starting position, but, similar to a pendulum, the period is around 2 years. All geosynchronous satellites not at 75 or 105 must perform periodic maneuvers to maintain their longitude.

Comment: 5. All stars.  :)

Answer (score 1):

A geostationary satellite does indeed move, relative to any location on or within the Earth. The Earth is of course rotating. The satellite remains above a fixed location on Earth's equator, but that only means that the satellite and the spot on Earth's equator have the same *angular* velocity around Earth's axis. If you consider *linear* velocity at any given instant, the satellite and the spot on the equator do have a relative velocity. In a coordinate system in which the Earth's center is at rest, the spot on the equator is moving in the direction of the Earth's rotation, but the satellite is moving in the direction of the Earth's rotation faster than the spot on the equator is.

Answer (score 0):

> You don't move relative to the center, neither do you move relative to any location on the Earth.

Another way of stating this is that you are at rest in a reference frame where the earth is also at rest.

However, since the earth is rotating, this reference frame is not an inertial reference frame.  Pseudo forces will appear that can complicate how things appear to move.

Instead it can be more convenient to use a reference frame centered at the earth's center, but which is not rotating.  Such a frame is good enough as an inertial frame.  Against this reference, the satellite is seen to accelerate due to the pull of earth's gravity as you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

A geostationary satellite in GSO moves relative to Earth with same angular velocity as if there is an invisible rod of some 36000 km from Earth's center firmly fixed to it..(sky hook)..

Any observer below  or locations on the Earth in the neighborhood always looks at it ( by means of radio contact) at same elevation angle to horizon.  It has 24 hour orbit period just like the Earth and so relatively it stays with us always up above the world so at same height.

By contast low earth orbit LEO satellites go roung too fast some 16 times a day.